# Ideal place to put React Error Boundary component?

Tags: reactjs

I recently tried out Error Boundaries of React. According to docs of react -

> The granularity of error boundaries is up to you. You may wrap top-level route components to display a “Something went wrong” message to the user, just like server-side frameworks often handle crashes. You may also wrap individual widgets in an error boundary to protect them from crashing the rest of the application.

Wrapping top-level routes are good and solve my purpose but a break in one component makes the other components that are working correctly useless and replaces all of them with the fall back UI of Error Boundary.

Like for example I have one top level Route component - `<Component1 />`
and it renders four other sub components - `<Component2 />` `<Component3 />` `<Component4 />` `<Component5 />`

Now my sub components have conditional rendering and if I want to use error boundary separately I need to wrap all my conditional rendering with an Error Boundary. Which I prefer not to.

I have another question: Does error boundary catches errors caused in lifecycle hooks (of the children component) like `ComponentDidMount`?

Eg -

```
cont Component1 = () => {
  return (
     <ErrorBoundary> 
         <Component2 />
         <Component3 />
         <Component4 />
         <Component5 />
     </ErrorBoundary>
 )
}
```

Does this `ErrorBoundary` catch errors in lifecycle hooks like componentDidMount of `Component2`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the text you quoted states, if you want to render all "working" sub-components, but replace the non-working one with the fallback, you need to wrap each sub-component with an error boundary. There is no real work-around for this. Perhaps you could use a more convenient pattern, such as [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) or [high-order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), but the effect is the same.

The "ideal place" to place an Error Boundary depends on where in your component-tree you want a fallback render to kick in if a branch fails. Perhaps you have a component that is very critical to the whole of your app - in that case maybe just a top-level Error boundary is enough since rendering the rest would be pointless. Maybe you have a less-important component - in that case wrap it in an Error boundary since the rest of the app should work, even without it.

---

> Does error boundary catches errors caused in lifecycle hooks (of the children component) like `ComponentDidMount`?

Yes. The top-level error boundary will catch the error generated from the sub-component, but the whole of `Component1` render will be replaced with the fallback render.

Error boundaries **do only** catch errors triggered through React's lifecycle methods (like `componentDidMount`), including the `render` method. Error boundaries **do not** catch errors triggered inside event handlers or any asynchronous code, such as `fetch`.

Comment: Does the ErrorBoundary catches the errors in lifecycle hooks inside the component it is used in? Like in here for Component1?

Comment: @AtinSingh, no. Only the sub-tree to the ErrorBoundary component. That said, nothing in `Component1` can break since it's a functional component with zero component logic.

Comment: So, if it only works for the sub-tree to the ErrorBoundary then I have no choice but to wrap the top-level route like `Component1` here. And btw this is just an example i picked up to explain things , the code that i tried this on actually had a complex component1

Comment: Yes, you'd need to wrap that one too.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.